# Set Default Image According To Gender - Carrierwave & Device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, carrierwave

I use carrierwave for image uploading but since i have no access in the image_uploader.rb to the var 'current_user' of devise gem i cannot set a default picture based on gender when ever the picture url is nil(after create or update), is there a work out?

uploaders/image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 def default_url
  if (current_user.gender == "Male")
   ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "male.PNG"].compact.join('_'))
  else
   ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "female.PNG"].compact.join('_'))
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the two photos "male/female.png" under `app/assets/images`

Then in the helpers/application_helper create this method

```
def default_img(user)
  if user.avatar_url.nil?           
    if (user.gender == "Male")
         "male.PNG"
    else
        "female.PNG"
    end
  else
    user.avatar_url
  end
end
```

Then use this method with each `img_tag`

Answer (score 2):

If `image_uploader.rb` is a module, call it in your `User.rb` model using a callback (e.g. `after_create`) passing the user object and setting the image based on the user's gender.

Something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_default_url!

  def set_default_url!
    url = ImageUploader.default_url(gender)
    update!(url: url)
  end
end
```

Then, in your module:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def self.default_url(gender)
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "#{gender.downcase}.PNG"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

Some code was obviously omitted for brevity.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `model.gender.downcase`? I believe that the Uploaded accesses it's calling record with the `model` method.

Comment: The `gender` argument passed into the `default_url` method is a string. I'm not passing the user object, just the value of `gender`.

Comment: Ah right, now I see it. I like this answer, it's clean and succinct.

Comment: image_uploader.rb is a class not a module, see the edit please.

Comment: Then you don't need to include the class.